# jinja2 - Showing image multiple times based on the if statment

Tags: python, if-statement, jinja2

1. I wanted to show `red.png` image `1` time and `grey.png` image `4`  times when the `key_val < 1.9`
2. I wanted to show `red.png` image `2` time and `grey.png` image `3`  times when the `key_val < 2.9`
3. I wanted to show `red.png` image `3` time and `grey.png` image `2`  times when the `key_val < 3.9`
4. I wanted to show `red.png` image `4` time and `grey.png` image `1`  times when the `key_val < 4.9`
5. I wanted to show `red.png` image `5` time and `grey.png` image `0`  times when the `key_val < 5`

   ```
   {% if key_val <= 1.9 %}
       <img src="red.png" alt="">
       <img src="grey.png" alt="">
   {% elif key_val <= 2.9 %}
       <img src="red.png" alt="">
       <img src="grey.png" alt="">
   {% elif key_val <= 3.9 %}
       <img src="red.png" alt="">
       <img src="grey.png" alt="">
   {% elif key_val <= 4.9 %}
       <img src="red.png" alt="">
       <img src="grey.png" alt="">
   {% elif key_val <= 5 %}
       <img src="red.png" alt="">
       <img src="grey.png" alt="">
   {% else %}
       <img src="grey.png" alt="">
   {% endif %}
   ```

Basically the problem is, i am getting numbers from the api based on that i have to show rating in email template. I am using jinja2 as templating language

Answer (score 1):

Try with the below code.

```
    {% if key_val <= 1.9 %}
        {% set red = 1 %}
        {% set grey = 4 %}
    {% elif key_val <= 2.9 %}
        {% set red = 2 %}
        {% set grey = 3 %}
    {% elif key_val <= 3.9 %}
        {% set red = 3 %}
        {% set grey = 2 %}
    {% elif key_val <= 4.9 %}
        {% set red = 4 %}
        {% set grey = 1 %}
    {% elif key_val <= 5 %}
        {% set red = 5 %}
        {% set grey = 0 %}
    {% else %}
        #put what you want yo do here
    {% endif %}

    {% for i in range(red)%}
        <img src="red.png" alt="">
    {% endfor %}
    {% for i in range(grey)%}
        <img src="grey.png" alt="">
    {% endfor %}
```